# How to call ViewController's method to show 2nd View?

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller, interrupt-handling

> //
>   // MyGameViewController.h
>   //
>      #import < UIKit/UIKit.h >
>      #import "SecondViewController.h"
>
> @interface MyGameViewController : UIViewController {
>   IBOutlet SecondViewController *secondViewController;
>   }
>   -(IBAction)goToSecondView;
>   @end
>
> ---
>
> //
>   // MyGameViewController.m
>   //
>      #import "MyGameViewController.h"
>
> @implementation MyGameViewController
>
> -(IBAction)goToSecondView{
>   [self presentModalViewController:secondViewController animated:YES];
>   }
>
> ---
>
> //
>   // MyGameView.h
>   //
>      #import < UIKit/UIKit.h >
>      #import "Sprite.h"
>
> @interface MyGameView : UIView {…}

Currently I have implemented a button on the MyGameView.xib to invoke the secondViewController view and it works. But I want the secondViewController get invoked by programming inside MyGameView.m when there is interruption, not by pressing a button. Therefore, I think there are 2 approaches:

a) Either make the goToSecondView method available to MyGameView.m
b) Implement all the code in MyGameViewController.h and MyGameViewController.m to MyGameView.m.

Issues:
1) When tried to make a) happen, I have to make goToSecondView method starting with (void), not (IBAction). But then how to invoke it in MyGameView.m?
2) I tried to do b) and implemented all code to MyGameView.m. But presentModalViewController is a method of ViewController and does not work in UIView. So what is the solution?

Answer (score 2):

As you stated, you can't call presentModalViewController in a UIView class. This seems like a great opportunity to use a delegate. You could do something along the lines of:

In MyGameView.h

```
@protocol MyGameViewDelegate
- (void)showSecondView;
@end

@interface MyGameView {
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <MyGameViewDelegate> delegate;
...
@end
```

In MyGameView.m, when you need to show the second view:

```
[self.delegate showSecondView];
```

In MyGameViewController.h:

```
#import "MyGameView.h"
@interface MyGameViewController : UIViewController <MyGameViewDelegate> {
...
```

In MyGameViewController.m:

```
#pragma mark MyGameViewDelegate methods

- (void)showSecondView {
    [self goToSecondView];
}
```

Note that you'll also need to set MyGameViewController to be the delegate of MyGameView. You could do that in Interface Builder, or in code, depending on where you create the two objects.

To do it in code, for example in the MyGameViewController.h viewDidLoad method:

```
myGameView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: Thanks for your detail reply. I am newbie and I am kind of lost. Most keywords you mentioned above are new to me, such has @protocol, #pragma mark ..., etc. 1) Would you mind explain what does the algorithm do? I have to create another delegate class so that an instance of it can be created? All the above looks different from typical declaration that I have been using. 2) what is **MyGameViewDelegate** referring to? Another .h.m files I have to create? 3) So how to set MyGameViewController to be the delegate of MyGameView? There are MyGameAppDelegate files existing already.

Comment: Protocols are a fundamental part of Objective-c. Any decent book will tell you about them. Apple's docs are at http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProtocols.html.